# Finding the top n represented entries in a grouped dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a beginner in R and would be very thankful for a response as I am stuck on this code (this is my attempt at solving the problem but it does not work):

```
personal_spotify_df <- fromJSON("data/StreamingHistory0.json")
personal_spotify_df = personal_spotify_df %>%
  mutate(minutesPlayed = msPlayed/1000/60)
  
personal_spotify_df_ranked <- personal_spotify_df %>%
  group_by(artistName) %>%
  filter(top_n(15, max(nrows())))
```

I have a dataframe (see below for a screenshot on how its structured) which is my spotity listening history. I want to group this dataframe by artists and afterwards arrange the new dataframe to show the top 15 artists with the most songs listened to. I am stuck on how to get from grouping by artistName to actually filtering out the top 15 represented artists from the dataframe.

[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HscCV.png)

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting for better clarification of the problem your are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `slice_max`, with `n` specified as 15 and the order column created with `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
personal_spotify_df %>%
  add_count(artistName, name = "Count") %>%  
  slice_max(n = 15, order_by = "Count") %>%
  select(-Count)
```

If we want to get only the top 15 distinct 'artistName',

```
personal_spotify_df %>%
    count(artistName, name = "Count") %>%
    slice_max(n = 15, order_by = "Count")
```

---

Or an option with `filter` after `arrange`ing the rows based on the count

```
personal_spotify_df %>%
   add_count(artistName) %>%
   arrange(desc(n)) %>%
   filter(artistName %in% head(unique(artistName), 15))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. I think you misunderstood the dataframe though. The msPlayed is not really relevant. This only measures how long a stream of a song was. What's important to me is how many streams songs of each artist had (One stream of a song equals one row). So I need the top 15 artist that have the most amount of row entries. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @noxrain just do a `count` by 'artistName`

Comment: I tried both. I like the second one. Output is almost good. It outputs a dataframe with 3644 rows though, I need 15. Right now it outputs ALL streams of the top 15 artists. I need the top 15 artists though with a count of how many streams. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @noxrain sorry, I thought you wanted to subset the rows from the whole data

Comment: @noxrain just change the `add_count` to `count` and it should work.  Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can make use of `table`, `sort` and `head` to get top 15 artists with their count

```
table(personal_spotify_df$artistName) |>
  sort(decreasing = TRUE) |>
  head(15) |>
  stack()
```

The pipe operator (`|>`) requires R 4.1 if you have a lower version use -

```
stack(head(sort(table(personal_spotify_df$artistName), decreasing = TRUE), 15))
```